# If user types ex. INF, all words that start with INF in a list are printed. How can I make a limit that only prints certain words?

Tags: python, list, limit

I have a list containing words that starts with "INF.." and "INFO.."

When user inputs in "INF", I don't want the words that start with INFO printed too. How can i make a limit so that the "info" words are not printed?

```
weirdList = {"INF432", "INF678", "INFO123", "INFO654"}
filtered_list = []

for word in weirdList
   if word[0:3] == input:
       filtered_list.append(word)
```

My wish is that only "INF432" and "INF678" gets printed, and not "INFO.." when the user asks for words starting with "INF"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From you examples, I could see that you want to keep only the items that start with "INF" and are followed by numbers.For example "INFO" is "INF" followed by a "O".

This can be achieved by this:

```
weirdList = {"INF432", "INF678", "INFO123", "INFO654"}
filtered_list = []

word1=input("enter something: ")

for word in weirdList:
   if word.startswith(word1) and word.replace(word1,"")[0].isnumeric():
     filtered_list.append(word)

print(filtered_list)
```

Output:

```
enter something: INF
['INF432', 'INF678']
```

This approach eliminates also "INFS01" and so on and works for other criteria than "INF".

Answer (score 0):

First, `weirdList` is a `set` not  a `list`. The reason your code doesn't work is because the condition is `True` for all your elements:

- `'INF432'[0:3]` will output `'INF'`
- `'INFO123'[0:3]` will also output `'INF'`

What you can do is filter out the items that start with `INFO`:

```py
weirdList = {"INF432", "INF678", "INFO123", "INFO654"}
filtered_list = []

for word in weirdList:
   if not word.startswith('INFO'):
       filtered_list.append(word)
```

This can also be achieved with a list comprehension:

```
weirdList = ["INF432", "INF678", "INFO123", "INFO654"]

filtered_list = [word for word in weirdList if not word.startswith('INFO')]
```

Note that in my last example I've changed the `weirdList` to an actual list.

If you want to add items to a list based on user input, and ignore the `INFO` items, you could do it like this:

```py
user_item_list = []
user_input = input('Enter item here: ')

if not user_input.startswith('INFO'):
    user_item_list.append(user_input)

print(user_item_list)
```